# How does Vue obtain the instance from the initial rendering every time Vue updates?

Tags: vue.js

if I have two files of Vue, as follows:

```
// human.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <cat></cat>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const humanConfig =  {
    data: {},
    methods: {}
        ...
    }
    export default humanConfig
</script>

// cat.vue
<template>
    <div>
        ....
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const catConfig =  {
    data: {},
    methods: {}
        ...
    }
    export default catConfig
</script>
```

in my opinion, if we have a component of 'human', Vue will create a vnode by human.vue, as follows:

```
const humanVnode = {
  type: {
    data: {
      /** data of human.vue */
    },
    methods: {
      /** methods of human.vue*/
    },
    render() {
      return {
        type: 'div',
        props: {},
        children: [
          /**catVnode */
          {
            type: {
              data: {
                /** data of cat.vue */
              },
              methods: {
                /** methods of cat.vue*/
              },
              render() {
                /**render of cat.vue */
              },
            },
            props: {},
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  },
  props: {},
}
```

when the human component renders for the first time, I guess that Vue will create a instance by humanVnode.type to store its state, then Vue will do 'humanVnode.type.render.call(humanInstance)' to create its subtree, the subtree is also a vnode, then we find that the we also need to create a instance by catVnode.type, then do the same thing like human.
my question is that when a variable changes， we need to rerender the human component, but how can we find the instance of cat component which is created for the first time ? is it in oldVnode of cat component? but where can we find the oldVnode of cat component ? is it in subtree? and subtree is in the instance of human component ?

expect someone who knows it help me to prove whether my ideas are right or wrong

Comment: you will benefit from reading https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#serverprefetch but to really catch how vue internal works take this read https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html#templates-vs-render-functions